# Git Merge conflicts in submodule. How to commit with their version?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-merge, tree-conflict

Basically I have read the git merge conflicts guide, and I'm not sure it directly addresses my situation. I have a conflict in submodules, and I just want to go with their version which I understand is `git diff -3 app/bundles` How do I just go with there version of the submodule, resolve the conflict and commit?

```
~/projects/sms/admin(rc)$ git diff
diff --cc app/bundles
index 999fd0a,ae6acdc..0000000
--- a/app/bundles
+++ b/app/bundles
~/projects/sms/admin(rc)$ git diff -1 app/bundles
* Unmerged path app/bundles
diff --git a/app/bundles b/app/bundles
index b34a733..999fd0a 160000
--- a/app/bundles
+++ b/app/bundles
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit b34a73375b4dfed6086d26d205ab5535acece053
+Subproject commit 999fd0a307e6d8d517ddf3dd6fab28a3ac0ec2c9
~/projects/sms/admin(rc)$ git diff -2 app/bundles
* Unmerged path app/bundles
~/projects/sms/admin(rc)$ git diff -3 app/bundles
* Unmerged path app/bundles
diff --git a/app/bundles b/app/bundles
index ae6acdc..999fd0a 160000
--- a/app/bundles
+++ b/app/bundles
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit ae6acdce79748ffba68504512536abf2b2b2ddf0
+Subproject commit 999fd0a307e6d8d517ddf3dd6fab28a3ac0ec2c9
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to get rid of all your changes in the submodule? If so, cd into the submodule, reset and commit the change into the outer repo.

`cd app/bundles`

**Please verify the hash again. All your changes will be lost.**

`git reset --hard ae6acdce79748ffba68504512536abf2b2b2ddf0`

`cd ../..`

`git add app/bundles`

`git commit`

Hope that is what you want to achieve.